# How to write a Jest unit testcases for an AEM React compoenent

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, aem

When I have code as below, how to write Jest testcase for `FiveGIntermediateEditConfig` to cover it?

```
const FiveGIntermediateEditConfig = {
  emptyLabel: "FiveG Intermediate",

  isEmpty() {
    return true;
  },
};

class FiveGIntermediateContainer extends Container {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fiveGInter">
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FiveGIntermediateContainer.defaultProps = {};

export default MapTo("vcg/components/soe-assisted/react/fiveGInter")(
  compose(withRouter)(FiveGIntermediateContainer, FiveGIntermediateEditConfig)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit is a Java framework so it won't be very useful in testing a React app. If you're looking for a JavaScript equivalent, consider https://jestjs.io/

Plain Jest is fine for any JavaScript that isn't strictly react-specific.

When it comes to React components, possible testing approaches are well-described in the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html

Most tools described there are just utilities that you plug into a test runner like Jest. Most, if not all examples, assume that Jest is used, but it's not a hard rule.